# How to ADD self-signed certificates to default certificates in HttpsURLConnection

Tags: java, android, ssl, httpsurlconnection

Good morning.

My problem is, I want to create a `HttpsURLConnection` that accepts default trusted certificates but also my self-signed certificated.

After looking around in Internet, I found a lot of similar questions, but not exactly what I want.

In particular, a good code is [here](https://gist.github.com/erickok/7692592).

This is pretty much what I want, but with a difference:
They will trust ONLY the self-signed certificates, I want to trust ALSO the self-signed certificates.

Basically I don't want to start from an empty `KeyStore`, I would like to get the default keystore, whatever/wherever it is, something that already contains the default certificates in my OS.

PS: I am working in Android.

Thanks to everyone

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You basically want to use the default trusted certificates as well as your own trusted certificates. Similar question and answers have been provided here: [Registering multiple keystores in JVM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1793979/registering-multiple-keystores-in-jvm)

I also ran into the same issue and found the answer of [Code a Ray](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16229909/6777695) really useful. After using his code snippet for multiple projects I created a library out of it. You can find it here: [sslcontext-kickstart](https://github.com/Hakky54/sslcontext-kickstart)

For your use case the following snipper with your certificates wrapped in a truststore file should do the trick:

```java
SSLFactory sslFactory = SSLFactory.builder()
    .withDefaultTrustMaterial()
    .withTrustMaterial("my-truststore.jks", "password".toCharArray())
    .build();

HttpsURLConnection httpsURLConnection = (HttpURLConnection) new URL(url).openConnection();
httpsURLConnection.setHostnameVerifier(sslFactory.getHostnameVerifier());
httpsURLConnection.setSSLSocketFactory(sslFactory.getSslContext().getSocketFactory());
```