# Is there any method to directly load a certificate & private key to SSLServerSocket (Java) programmatically?

Tags: java, ssl, certificate, private-key

I am from a 'C' background. I am trying to analyze how to write a Java SSL Server.

So, far the examples I found talk about loading certificate and private to a Key Store and the programmatically associating the KeyStore to SSLContext and then create a SSLServerSocket from the same.

But, are there any methods for directly mentioning which certificate the SSLServerSocket should use? Also, even if I use keystore and if there are multiple certificates and keys how can I specify to SSLServerSocket which one it should use?

Any sample link will be helpful.

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1788031

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I was saying in a comment, in an [answer to one of your questions earlier](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6370745/can-we-load-multiple-certificates-keys-in-a-key-store/6371359#6371359), you'll need to use a `KeyManager` to do this.

There are various ways of doing this. [jSSLutils](http://www.jsslutils.org/) is a library that can make it a bit more convenient (but you could also do it more manually). There's an example with the [FixedServerAliasKeyManager](http://code.google.com/p/jsslutils/wiki/SSLContextFactory#FixedServerAliasKeyManager). One of the shortest ways to do it would be to use something like this:

```
X509SSLContextFactory sslContextFactory = new X509SSLContextFactory();
// By default, this would use the keystore passed with the usual system properties.

sslContextFactory.setKeyManagerWrapper(
    new FixedServerAliasKeyManager.Wrapper("the-alias-you-want"));
// You could read the alias name from a custom system property, for example.

SSLContext sslContext = sslContextFactory.buildSSLContext("TLS");
SSLServerSocketFactory sslServerSocketFactory = sslContext.getServerSocketFactory();
```